# Calculation of the non-Gaussity parameter for primordial cosmological perturbations by the ADM Formalism

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, hamiltonian-formalism, adm-formalism

Maldacena has used the [ADM Formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism) in one of his papers (http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0210603) in computing the the three point correlation function (i.e the non-Gaussianity) parameter for primordial cosmological perturbations. Can somebody explain in some more detail the relevant parts of the ADM formalism needed to do understand this calculation?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you hoping to find here that you couldn't get by searching Google for "ADM formalism"? As it is, this question is pretty vague.

Comment: Question with a huge overlap, if not an exact duplicate http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3445/

Comment: I mentioned about the paper of Maldacena in my question. (http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0210603). I need to know ADM Formalism so that I can understand whatever is said there. A results given by a simple Google search on ADM is not good enough. Either they are not enough (somewhat qualitative) or they are too difficult and assumes a lot.

Comment: Pretty much any standard advanced GR textbook has a chapter on ADM.

Comment: Hi @Debangshu, if you want to understand Maldacena's calculation of these three point correlation functions, you should edit your question (or ask a new one) to primarly ask about this. It might well be that an answerer points you to some relevant reading material about the ADM formalism anyway. Good look ;-).