# Hamiltonian formalism of General Relativity Textbook

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism, education, adm-formalism

I've been reading Wald's book on General Relativity and in appendix $E_{2}$ it discusses the Hamiltonian formalism of General Relativity.I would like to understand it more, can you recommend me a textbook about ADM formalism?

P.S.
I have already read Eric Poisson book too.

Answer (score 3):

I can only point you to the summary by R. Arnowitt, S. Deser, C.W. Misner "The Dynamics of General Relativity", p. 227 from "Gravitation: An Introduction to Current Research", Editor Louis Witten, John Wiley & Sons, 1962.

from which you can see the original list of articles by the trio:

Arnowitt, R., and S. Deser, 1959, Phys. Rev., 113, 745 (I).

--- S. Deser, and C. W. Misner:

1959, Phys. Rev., 116, 1322 (II).

1960, Phys. Rev., 117, 1595 (III).

1960, Nuov. Cim., 15, 487.

1960, Phys. Rev. Letters, 4, 375.

1960, Phys. Rev., 118, 1100 (IV).

1960, J. Math. Phys., 1,434 (IIIA).

1960, Phys. Rev., 120, 313 (V).

1960, Phys. Rev., 120, 321 (VA).

1960, Ann. Phys., 11, 116 (VB).

1961, Nuov. Cim., 19, 668 OVA).

1961, Phys. Rev., 121, 1556 (IVB).

1961, Phys. Rev., 122, 997 (IVG).

Answer (score 0):

Besides the original literature DanielC enumerated,

- Bojowald's *Canonical Gravity and Applications* is specifically about the Hamiltonian formalism;
- D'Inverno's *Introducing Einstein's Relativity* has a fairly good introduction to the Hamiltonian formalism, as well, but simpler...more friendly for students (I'd imagine).